# SQL a JPQL con Subconsulta

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

se me presenta una situación que le he dado vueltas desde hace un par de días, tengo tres tablas en la base de datos:

```
Almacenes
---------
id
codigo 
nombre

fechas_procesos
---------------
id
fecha

control_procesos
--------------------
id
idAlmacen
idFechaProceso
```

La tabla `almacenes` contiene la información de 3 almacenes, la tabla `fechas_procesos` contienen las fechas en que los almacenes deben enviar información a la principal y la tabla `control_procesos` lleva el historial de procesos que cada almacen ha realizado.
Las tablas `almacenes` y `fechas_procesos` tienen una relación, cada una, de uno a muchos con la tabla `control_procesos`.
Cada tabla tiene su correspondiente entidad en codigo (Almacen, FechaProceso, ControlProceso).

Cuando un almacen envia la información de una fecha de proceso se registra en la tabla `control_procesos` el almacen y la fecha del proceso que se realizó. Ejemplo de datos

```
Almacenes
id    codigo    nombre
--    ------    ------------
1     A1        Almacen1
2     A2        Almacen2
3     A3        Almacen3

fechas_procesos
id    fecha          
--    ----------     
1     2018-10-31    
2     2018-11-30
3     2018-12-31

control_procesos
id    idAlmacen    idFechaProceso
--    ----------   ---------------
1     1            1
2     2            1
3     3            1
4     1            2
5     2            2
```

La situación es la siguiente, para una fecha de proceso dada, debo obtener las lista de almacenes que no han realizado el proceso, es decir que no esten registrados en la tabla `control_procesos` con esa fecha. Para el ejemplo de los datos anteriores las salida serían

> Si la fecha es 2018-10-31 no deberia devolver datos dado que todos los almacenes ya enviaron la información.
>
> Si la fecha es 2018-11-30 Solo deberia devolver el almacen 3 que es el que no ha realizado el proceso, y
>
> Si la fecha es 2018-12-31 Deberia devolver los tres almacenes.

No he podido realizar la consulta `jpql` que me resuelva el problema, hasta hoy pude encontrar una sentencia `sql` usando una `subconsulta`, pero no se como pasarla a `jpql` la consulta es:

```
select * from almacenes a 
    left join (select * from control_procesos ctr
                inner join fechas_procesos fp
                on ctr.idFechaProceso = fp.id
                where ctr.idfechaproceso = 2) ct 
    on ct.idAlmacen = a.id 
    where ct.id is null;
```

Agradezco de su colaboración y aesoria de como poder hacer la consulta en `jpql`. Gracias